# Connect with username in Sylius

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, sylius

sylius use unless email to connect to the administration,

I want to use username and email in parallel, but it does not work

security.yml

```
      security:
          providers:
              fos_userbundle:
                  id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
          encoders:
              FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
          firewalls:
              administration:
                  switch_user: true
                  context:     user
                  pattern:     /administration/.*
                  form_login:
                      provider:     fos_userbundle
                      login_path:   /administration/login
                      check_path:   /administration/login-check
                      failure_path: /administration/login
                      default_target_path: /administration/dashboard
                      use_forward:  false
                      use_referer:  true
                  logout:
                      path:   /administration/logout
                      target: /administration/login
                  anonymous: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check weather the username is different from the email?
In Sylius the user gets the same username as his email address as you can see in

```
Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\User


class User{
...

public function setEmail($email)
{
    parent::setEmail($email);
    $this->setUsername($email);

    return $this;
}

public function setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical)
{
    parent::setEmailCanonical($emailCanonical);
    $this->setUsernameCanonical($emailCanonical);

    return $this;
}
}
```